# How to include a new string with variable on a new column created in a .csv file in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

**I have a .csv like:**

```
location,num1,num2,min,avg,med,max,std,
1344 and 640, 278.000000,8215.000000,0.000000,0.475325,0.465546;0.985196,0.168458,
```

**I want to include on first line the String 'ID' and on second line a variable with the ID as:**

```
ID,location,num1,num2,min,avg,med,max,std,
134085,1344 and 640, 278.000000,8215.000000,0.000000,0.475325,0.465546;0.985196,0.168458,
```

**I don't know how to include the ID variable on the second line. This .csv must be saved with the new result.**

Comment: Your `csv` file has exactly two lines? Where to take the new ID from?

Comment: @Stephan The new ID is taken from the folder name that the .csv is in. After the header with the 'ID', the number of rows can be more than one. This must iterate from other files. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72841958/how-to-include-the-folder-name-from-second-row-on-csv-file-in-batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be used the following batch file code for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("input.csv") do echo ID,%%I>"output.csv"& goto DataRows
:DataRows
(for /F usebackq^ skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("input.csv") do echo 134085,%%I)>>"output.csv"
rem if exist "output.csv" move /Y "output.csv" "input.csv"
endlocal
```

The first `for /F` processes just the first line of the file with name `input.csv` in current directory. The used `for /F` options define an empty list of string delimiters and no end of line character to get the entire line in the CSV file of which file name is enclosed in double quotes assigned to the loop variable `I` without ignoring any non-empty line. This line is output with `ID,` at the beginning and the output is written into a new file with name `output.csv` in the current directory.

The command **GOTO** results in jumping for further processing to the command line below the label `DataRows` after processing the first line from the file `input.csv`.

This time the entire `for /F` command line is enclosed in round brackets to open first the already existing file `output.csv` and let it open all the time on appending one line after the other from `input.csv` with skipped first line and `134085,` inserted at beginning of each data row output with command **ECHO** and redirected into the permanently opened file `output.csv` until all lines are processed.

The last but one line is commented out. Remove the command `rem` if the created file `output.csv` should replace the file `input.csv` in the current directory.

The syntax with specifying the `for /F` options not with an argument string enclosed in `"` is unusual, but the only method which exist to define an empty list of string delimiters and no end of line character by using `delims=` and `eol=` with `eol=` at end of the argument string. It is necessary to escape each equal sign and each space with caret character `^` in this case as the options are not enclosed in `"` to get each space and each equal sign interpreted initially as literal characters by `cmd.exe` on processing the command line instead of argument string separators as usual before the command **FOR** interprets the argument string with the options which does not contain anymore any `^`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `rem /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- Microsoft documentation [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)