# How to include the folder name from second row on .CSV file in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My code isn't working.

This is my working path:

```
Parent Folder
  |
  |-------> 1
  |         |-------> result.csv -------> x,y,z,...,
  |                                       a,b,c,...,
  |                                       .
  |                                       .
  |-------> 2                             
  |         |-------> result.csv -------> x,y,z,...,
  |                                       d,e,f,...,
  |                                       .
  |                                       .
  |-------> 3
  |         |-------> result.csv -------> x,y,z,...,
  .                                       f,g,h,...,
  .                                       .
  .                                       .
```

This is what I want:

```
Parent Folder
  |
  |-------> 1
  |         |-------> result.csv -------> ID,x,y,z,...,
  |                                       1,a,b,c,...,
  |                                       1,...,
  |                                       .
  |-------> 2                             
  |         |-------> result.csv -------> ID,x,y,z,...,
  |                                       2,d,e,f,...,
  |                                       2,...,
  |                                       .
  |-------> 3
  |         |-------> result.csv -------> ID,x,y,z,...,
  .                                       3,g,h,i,...,
  .                                       3,...,
  .                                       .
```

This is what I have (working on parent folder directory):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%a in ('dir /a:d /b') do (
    set id=%%a
    cd !id!
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("result.csv") do echo ID,%%I>"output.csv"& 
    goto DataRows
    :DataRows
    (for /F usebackq^ skip^=1^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("result.csv") do echo !id!,%%I)>>"output.csv"
    rem if exist "output.csv" move /Y "output.csv" "input.csv"
)

pause >nul
```

I've tried to change the first for to: `for /d %%a in (*) do (` but did not work too.

After that I want to merge all .csv into one dataset in the following format:

```
ID,x,y,z,...,
1,a,b,c,...,
1,...,
.
2,d,e,f,...,
2,...,
.
3,g,h,i,...,
3,...,
.
```

Comment: You cannot use `goto` and a label in a parenthesised block of code; move that portion into a sun-routine and use `call` to call it…

Comment: You have explicitly disabled `delayedexpansion`. In order to have the `!var!` return the current value, you must ENABLE delayedexpansion. You are executing a `cd` to the subdirectory which makes *that* destination directory current. You need to `cd` back at the end of the loop.

Comment: @aschipfl How will I get inside the file and edit the .csv without being inside the folders? Suggestion?

Comment: @Magoo You're right!

Answer (score 0):

You have not enabled delayed expansion but you are trying to use it (in `!id!`). So either enable it, or avoid it by replacing `set id=%%a` and `cd !id!` by `cd %%a`, or even better, `cd "%%a"`.
Though I would generally avoid `cd` in your situation…

A label and `goto` cannot be used within a parenthesised block of code like a `for` loop, so you have to move that portion out of the block (for example, by using a sub-routine and using `call`), or by changing your logic and generally avoiding them.

To solve your path issue, replace `for /f %%a in ('dir /a:d /b') do (` by `for /D %%a in ("D:\Full\Path\To\Parent Folder\*") do (` and precede every CSV file name with the iterated parent; for instance, `"result.csv"` becomes `"%%~a\result.csv"` then.
If the batch script resides in the parent directory and you do not want to explicitly specify it, you could replace its full path by `%~dp0.` which points to the parent directory of the batch file.

This is how I would write the script:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Alternatively replace `%~dp0*` by `D:\Full\Path\To\Parent Folder\*`:
for /D %%a in ("%~dp0*") do (
    rem // Avoid to reprocess already processed files:
    findstr "^ID," "%%~a\result.csv" > nul || (
        set "FLAG=#" & rem // This flag indicates whether the header is to be processed.
        > "%%~a\output.csv" (
            for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("%%~a\result.csv") do (
                if defined FLAG (
                    echo ID,%%I
                    set "FLAG=" & rem // At this point said flag is cleared after the header.
                ) else (
                    rem // Delayed expansion is avoided by directly using the loop reference:
                    echo %%~nxa,%%I
                )
            )
        )
        rem // Replace the original CSV file:
        move /Y "%%~a\output.csv" "%%~a\result.csv" > nul
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to EnableDelayedExpansion to output the .csv file with the name of the folder instead of 'output.csv' (with !a!), but CMD echoes "Access is Denied". This is because of the "%~dp0*"?  This occurs with `for /D %%a in (*) do (` too. Suggestion to merge all the .csv but only with only one top header?